# How to hide comment lines in the Visual Studio Code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

Sometimes, configuration files contain a lot of comment lines for options explanations and default values.

Is there a way to hide comment lines in the Visual Studio Code editor?

Actually a switch button would be nice, with automatic recognition of comment lines, depending on the file extension.

As a turn around, I have to open a terminal and filter the file with:

```
egrep -v -e "^[[:space:]]*$|^[[:space:]]*;.*$|^[[:space:]]*#.*$" some_file.conf
```

Comment: customize the theme to make the comments transparent

Comment: you can use the extension [Remove Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-remove-comments)

Comment: I don't want to remove them, just to hide them on demand